# Change a cron job from calling via url (curl) to calling via local command line (PHP)

Tags: php, curl, cron

I have one cron file with name `cron.php`.
Inside it I'm using `curl_multi` approach to start sub parallel tasks.

Example:
The crontab of cpanel will execute this every minute.

```
curl http://mywebsite.com/cron.php
```

Inside `cron.php` I have `curl_multi` code that call another file called **`sub-crons.php`**. The first one will be **`http://mywebsite.com/sub-crons.php?cron_key=1`**, second will be **`http://mywebsite.com/sub-crons.php?cron_key=2`** and so on.

And this is the problem, I want use the php command like this:

```
php /path/to/my/cron.php
```

I can do that with the first `cron.php` file but it will call the other file (for sub tasks in url and I want it to call it in PHP `path/to/sub-crons.php?cron_key=1`).

Can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

A file on disk doesn't have query parameters. Query parameters are only used in ***URLs***, which are irrelevant when executing a local file on the command line.

Your invocation needs to look more like:

```
php path/to/sub-crons.php 1
```

Inside the script you need to use `$argv[1]` to retrieve the parameter instead of `$_GET`.