# Running sub tasks in parallel via crontab

Tags: php

I want to make some scheduled tasks via cron tab and php from another cron job.

I want to call this from crontab:

```
php path/to/my/cron.php
```

In `cron.php` I want to execute separate parallel tasks in the same time.

Something like that:

*cron.php*:

```
#first task,#second task
```

That will start in the same time.

How can I do that?

I used multiple curl and it will not do what I want
[Change a cron job from calling via url (curl) to calling via local command line (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35412378/change-a-cron-job-from-calling-via-url-curl-to-calling-via-local-command-line).

Comment: use thread http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php

Comment: You should use this, is very simple: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/

Comment: thanks guys but it want a lib or extension will be available in  shared hosting, my product is not private

Comment: Perhaps something like [artax](https://github.com/amphp/artax) does what you want (what it is is not clear from your question).

Comment: @PeeHaa it will do the same as curl multiple

Comment: I can't understand your question. What prevents you from adding as many lines as you want with the same schedule? What cron tool are you talking about exactly, since it doesn't seem to be the standard Unix one?

Comment: And what is "the same"?  As stated before you never said what you want to do.